# How can I call an Oracle stored procedure with object parameter for input in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm beginner in Oracle, I have written this object in Oracle:

```
create or replace 
TYPE behzadtype AS OBJECT 
( /* TODO enter attribute and method declarations here */ 
  SESSIONID Number,
  myID Number

)
```

and this stored procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2(temp in behzadtype) AS 
BEGIN
   insert into beh values(temp.myID,'behiheib');
END PROCEDURE2;
```

My question: how can I call this stored procedure from C#? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add references by right clicking on your project name in solution explorer >Add Reference >.Net then Add namespaces.

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data;
```

then paste this code in event Handler

```
  string str = "User ID=username;Password=password;Data Source=Test";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(str);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PROCEDURE2", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    --Ad parameter list--
    // cmd.Parameters.Add("parameter_name", "varchar2").Value = value;
    ....
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And its Done.

Comment: Hi Ali,what write the into the parameter_name?object name?

Comment: Hi Behzad. write such this : `cmd.Parameters.Add("temp", "behzadtype").Value = value`